# Tracking the progress and convergence of optimization

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, differential-evolution

I have an optimization problem with 36 variables.

I am using `differential_evolution` from `scipy`, I specify `popsize=15, recombination=0.1, mutation=(0.9,1), strategy="best1bin", worker=1`. I also print out intermediate results using callback. For example:

```
differential_evolution step 406: f(x)= 3182.8
[ 0.26630986  0.5777863   0.45482344  0.66859366  0.43145427  0.80049072  0.94042629  0.74227126  0.76609957  0.39421997  0.32598765  0.3198547   0.11332792  0.47842094
  0.41399388  0.16792322  0.24380912  0.74006486 -0.05026967  0.25951122  0.06112132  0.10108828  0.10494785 -0.38002972  0.1290126  -0.03676165  0.22189568  0.2424713
 -0.07450294 -0.52599295  0.1081112   0.41711925  0.12989419  0.63397135 -0.75419418 -0.38192472] convergence:  0.0
```

Is population evaluated sequentially if with `worker=1`, and how does it relate to `convergence` in `callback`?

Specifically, how should I understand the results here?
It's already at step of 406, and convergence is still 0.0. Can I see it as no sign of convergence after evaluations of 406 populations? But the callback has reported this value of fun since step 321?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is population evaluated sequentially if with worker=1

Yes, although if you use the `vectorized` option (see [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.differential_evolution.html)) you can calculate the objective function for many members of the population in one vectorized call, which may be faster than looping in Python.

> and how does it relate to convergence in callback?
> Can I see it as no sign of convergence after evaluations of 406 populations?

It depends. Here is how `convergence` is calculated, and then we'll see how it can be 0.

- The value of `convergence` that gets passed to the callback is the
  relative tolerance `tol` divided by the internal measure of
  convergence, `self.converged` ([source](https://%60https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/4edfcaa3ce8a387450b6efce968572def71be089/scipy/optimize/_differentialevolution.py#L1179-L1182%60))
- The internal measure of convergence is the standard deviation of
  population energies divided by the absolute value of the mean
  ([source](https://%60https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/4edfcaa3ce8a387450b6efce968572def71be089/scipy/optimize/_differentialevolution.py#L1100-L1108%60)).
- The population energies are the objective function value for each
  member of the population ([source](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/4edfcaa3ce8a387450b6efce968572def71be089/scipy/optimize/_differentialevolution.py#L1288)).

So if the function value is very spread out among members of the population, you can get very small `convergence`.

However, to be exactly zero, one of three things must happen:

- relative tolerance `tol` has to be `0`,
- population standard deviation is so large relative to the mean that the `converged` calculation underflows, or
- one of your population energies is infinite ([source](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/4edfcaa3ce8a387450b6efce968572def71be089/scipy/optimize/_differentialevolution.py#L1114-L1115)).

I would suggest taking a look at the individual energies (objective function values) to get an idea of which is the case (the last, if I were to guess). If your callback function has the signature

```
callback(intermediate_result: OptimizeResult)
```

in which the single argument is named `intermediate_result`, it receives an intermediate `OptimizeResult` object with attribute `population_energies`, which will allow you to see all the individual population energies ([source](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/4edfcaa3ce8a387450b6efce968572def71be089/scipy/optimize/_differentialevolution.py#L1263)).

---

Based on your comment, it sounds like at least one feasible solution is found, but some members of the population have not found a feasible solution after many iterations. Consequently, their associated energy is infinite, and `convergence` is still exactly zero.

If you're sure the constraints are correct and you can't loosen them to make them easier to satisfy, you have a few options.

- Instead of using the `constraints` feature, evaluate the constraints yourself, and add a [penalty component](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penalty_method) to the objective function that penalizes constraint violation. This would allow you to see a nonzero `convergence` number even when some members of the population violate constraints. However, population members that don't satisfy the constraints may still have very high energies relative to those that do, causing `convergence` to remain very low, so I wouldn't necessarily recommend this approach.
- Use the information available in `intermediate_result` to define your own convergence criteria, and raise a `StopIteration` when you're satisfied with the results.
- After finding a few feasible solutions, restart optimization using the best feasible solution as a guess. Perhaps this will help other members of the population achieve feasibility. (OTOH I don't remember how the guess is used, so this might not be true.)
- Just set `maxiter` to the number of iterations you're willing to wait for, and let `differential_evolution` do its best in the number of iterations allotted. If it doesn't think it has converged in the number of iterations allotted, that doesn't necessarily mean that the best solution it found isn't good enough for your purposes. It's all heuristics anyway; there's no guarantee that `convergence=1` means that the global optimum has been found or that if `convergence=0` the globally optimal solution *hasn't* been found. Ultimately, you are the judge of whether the solution is good enough.

Comment: I did notice the first 100 steps all have `fun=inf`. I thought this is related to the constraint I set. It progressed very rapidly for the first 100 steps, so I thought it simply ruling out the members of population that do not meet the constraint. How could I solve this problem?

Comment: Yes, the energy reported to the callback will be infinite if no members of the population satisfy the constraints. I've added some thoughts on addressing the problem to the bottom of my answer.