# How to check if a matrix is a var-covariance matrix as a constraint for optimization

Tags: python, optimization, covariance-matrix, differential-evolution

I am doing an optimization where the parameters need to be estimated are variance-covariance matrix. And I am using `differential_evolution` from `scipy` for the optimation.

```
def likelihood(params):
    p = params[0] # this parameter is not related to var-covar matrix
    dev = np.diag(params[8:15])
    X = np.eye(dev.shape[0])
    X[0, 1:7] = params[15:21]
    X[1, 2:7] = params[21:26]
    X[2, 3:7] = params[26:30]
    X[3, 4:7] = params[30:33]
    X[4, 5:7] = params[33:35]
    X[5, 6:7] = params[35:36]
    X = X + X.T - np.diag(np.diag(X))
    cov = dev.dot(X).dot(dev)
    L = np.linalg.cholesky(cov)
    
    # only for reproduce.
    arg1 = -0.2 * np.sqrt(0.5 * (params[0] ** 2 + params[1] ** 2))
    arg2 = 0.5 * (np.cos(2. * np.pi * params[0]) + np.cos(2. * np.pi * params[1]))
    return -20. * np.exp(arg1) - np.exp(arg2) + 20. + np.e + params.sum()
    

def constrain(params):
    dev = np.diag(params[8:15])
    X = np.eye(dev.shape[0])
    X[0, 1:7] = params[15:21]
    X[1, 2:7] = params[21:26]
    X[2, 3:7] = params[26:30]
    X[3, 4:7] = params[30:33]
    X[4, 5:7] = params[33:35]
    X[5, 6:7] = params[35:36]
    X = X + X.T - np.diag(np.diag(X))
    cov = dev.dot(X).dot(dev)
    try:
        np.linalg.cholesky(cov)
        return 0
    except np.linalg.LinAlgError:
        return 1

def print_de(x, convergence):
    print(x,"convergence: ",convergence)

bounds = (((0.0, 1.0),) * 8 + ((0.0, 1.0),) + ((0.0, 0.5),) * 6 + ((-1.0,1.0),)*21)
differential_evolution(likelihood, bounds=bounds, disp=True,
                       callback=print_de,
                       constraints=NonlinearConstraint(constrain, 0, 0)
                      )
```

For the first 100 steps from the callback, `f(x)=inf`, and it progresses very fast.
I tried to verify one `x`, and it does not meet the constraint. So I believe all these first 100 steps are ruling out `x` that do not meet the constraint.

However, it seems that this causes problem of non-convergence. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77899674/tracking-the-progress-and-convergence-of-optimization).

So my question is how to verify var-covariance matrix without affecting convergence?

Edit:

I added an optimization problem from the documentation for reproduce only. In this example, it shows the first couple steps have `f(x)=inf`, but it does give `convergence>0` which is different from my actual problem, where I am only getting `convergence=0.0` so far (at the step 458).

Comment: The documentation for `LinAlgError` in this case is _If the decomposition fails, for example, if a is not positive-definite_ . What is the specific error you expect to be raised? This is very important, because you should break apart your call to `cholesky` and replace it with a continuous feasibility measure.

Comment: Because a positive definite matrix is a var-cov matrix, so I am thinking to check if a matrix is positive definite, then I want to use this to check if a matrix is var-cov matrix or not. And also I have to do `np.linalg.cholesky(cov)` anyway in the `likelihood`, so I am thinking I should check beforehand using `cholesky`.

Comment: Don't. Read e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/16270026/313768 . One continuous method is to return all of the eigenvalues, and set the bound of the constraint to be 0. The optimizer will better "understand" when it is approaching the bound.

Comment: This is not particularly a minimum reproducible example - are parameters 1 through 7 used at all?

Comment: yes, 1-7 are the means of the variables, 8-35 are standard errors and correlation coefficients. To reproduce, I think can simply drop params[0:7].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking a series of wild guesses about the nature of your data, you don't actually need differential evolution. Use plain-old `minimize`, and as I said in the comments, don't attempt a `cholesky` in the constraint - instead, use a [continuous proxy metric](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16270026/313768) that implies positive definiteness when the bounds are met. This runs without problem:

```py
import numpy as np
import numpy.linalg
from scipy.optimize import minimize, NonlinearConstraint


def unpack(params: np.ndarray) -> tuple[
    float,       # p
    np.ndarray,  # variable means
    np.ndarray,  # standard errors
    np.ndarray,  # correlation coefficients
    np.ndarray,  # covariance
]:
    (p,), means, dev_diag, X_triu = np.split(params, (1, 8, 15))
    dev = np.diag(dev_diag)
    n = dev_diag.size
    X = np.zeros((n, n))
    X[np.triu_indices(n=n, k=1)] = X_triu
    X += X.T + np.eye(n)
    cov = dev @ X @ dev

    return p, means, dev, X, cov


def likelihood(params: np.ndarray) -> float:
    p, means, dev, X, cov = unpack(params)

    try:
        L = np.linalg.cholesky(cov)
    except numpy.linalg.LinAlgError:
        return means.size**2

    return p - L.sum()  # bogus


def positive_definite(params: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    p, means, dev, X, cov = unpack(params)
    return np.real(np.linalg.eigvals(cov))


bounds = (
      (( 0.0, 1.0),)*8
    + (( 0.0, 1.0),)
    + (( 0.0, 0.5),)*6
    + ((-1.0, 1.0),)*21
)
result = minimize(
    fun=likelihood,
    x0=np.concatenate((
        (0,),
        np.zeros(7),
        np.ones(7),
        np.zeros(7*6//2)
    )),
    bounds=bounds,
    constraints=NonlinearConstraint(positive_definite, lb=0, ub=np.inf),
)
assert result.success
p, means, dev, X, cov = unpack(result.x)
np.set_printoptions(linewidth=200)
print('cost:', result.fun)
print('p:', p)
print('means:', means)
print('dev:')
print(dev)
print('X:')
print(X)
print('cov:')
print(cov)
print('eigenvalues:', positive_definite(result.x))
```

```
cost: -7.2387859198084925
p: 9.7150304110818e-16
means: [7.27948618e-15 5.87216902e-15 7.23738763e-14 2.36667516e-14 1.04145402e-15 3.84911146e-14 7.87661099e-15]
dev:
[[1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0. ]
 [0.  0.5 0.  0.  0.  0.  0. ]
 [0.  0.  0.5 0.  0.  0.  0. ]
 [0.  0.  0.  0.5 0.  0.  0. ]
 [0.  0.  0.  0.  0.5 0.  0. ]
 [0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.5 0. ]
 [0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.5]]
X:
[[1.         0.70748057 0.57765563 0.50015331 0.4474081  0.40859447 0.37793046]
 [0.70748057 1.         0.81654105 0.70737526 0.63253508 0.57763506 0.53445386]
 [0.57765563 0.81654105 1.         0.8663462  0.77468924 0.70720782 0.65472736]
 [0.50015331 0.70737526 0.8663462  1.         0.89428674 0.81661324 0.75591993]
 [0.4474081  0.63253508 0.77468924 0.89428674 1.         0.91300002 0.84509787]
 [0.40859447 0.57763506 0.70720782 0.81661324 0.91300002 1.         0.92577982]
 [0.37793046 0.53445386 0.65472736 0.75591993 0.84509787 0.92577982 1.        ]]
cov:
[[1.         0.35374028 0.28882782 0.25007665 0.22370405 0.20429723 0.18896523]
 [0.35374028 0.25       0.20413526 0.17684382 0.15813377 0.14440876 0.13361346]
 [0.28882782 0.20413526 0.25       0.21658655 0.19367231 0.17680196 0.16368184]
 [0.25007665 0.17684382 0.21658655 0.25       0.22357168 0.20415331 0.18897998]
 [0.22370405 0.15813377 0.19367231 0.22357168 0.25       0.22825    0.21127447]
 [0.20429723 0.14440876 0.17680196 0.20415331 0.22825    0.25       0.23144496]
 [0.18896523 0.13361346 0.16368184 0.18897998 0.21127447 0.23144496 0.25      ]]
eigenvalues: [1.72809096 0.52824861 0.12663946 0.05380617 0.03070819 0.01962472 0.01288189]
```